# can't set resolution 1680x1050 in NVIDIA driver (Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes))

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Ubuntu 16.04, GeForce9600GT, driver NVIDIA 304.131, same with 340.96, cabel VGA.

I can't set resolution 1680x1050 in NVIDIA driver (Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes))

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1360x768      59.96    59.80  
   1152x864      60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   680x384       59.96    59.80  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       72.19  
   320x240       60.05  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

cvt 1680 1050:

```
# 1680x1050 59.95 Hz (CVT 1.76MA) hsync: 65.29 kHz; pclk: 146.25 MHz
Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

xrandr --newmode:

```
 sudo xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00" 146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1680x1050_60.00:

```
 X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

Answer (score 0):

cabel DVI instead of VGA solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you got it to autodetect.  I wish someone knew how to fix the xrandr addmode bug.